Shortcut edges in DAG
I am looking for an efficient algorithm for the following problem:
An edge (u,v) in a graph G is called a shortcut if there is a path from u to v of length more than 1. Given a DAG, Find all shortcuts.
Is there an algorithm that takes O(|V|+|E|) for this problem?
